# create Excel sheet between existing sheet using poi 3.16

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have 4 sheets( lets **AA**,**BB**, **CC** & **DD**) in my workbook. I have the following requirement: I want to remove sheet **BB** and want to inset a new sheet **BB_Error**.

I am able to remove the **BB** sheet using `"my_workbook.removeSheetAt(index);"`. Also able to create a new sheet using `"my_workbook.createSheet("BB_Error");"`.

Now, I have used `"my_workbook.setSheetOrder("BB_Error", index);"`, to reorder the newly created sheet. While I debug the code, workbook is getting generated but, when I run my code I am getting the below error:

> Could not run 'createExcel'
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: calculated end index (888984) is out of allowable range (888980..888983)
>
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: calculated end index (888984) is out of allowable range (888980..888983)
>       at org.apache.poi.util.LittleEndianByteArrayOutputStream.(LittleEndianByteArrayOutputStream.java:41)
>       at org.apache.poi.hssf.record.StandardRecord.serialize(StandardRecord.java:45)
>       at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook$SheetRecordCollector.serialize(HSSFWorkbook.java:1259)
>       at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.getBytes(HSSFWorkbook.java:1305)
>       at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.write(HSSFWorkbook.java:1205)
>       at lavika.createExcel(lavika.java:733)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at com.wm.app.b2b.server.JavaService.baseInvoke(JavaService.java:443)
>       at com.wm.app.b2b.server.invoke.InvokeManager.process(InvokeManager.java:648)
>       at com.wm.app.b2b.server.util.tspace.ReservationProcessor.process(ReservationProcessor.java:39)
>       at com.wm.app.b2b.server.invoke.StatisticsProcessor.process(StatisticsProcessor.java:49)
>       at com.wm.app.b2b.server.invoke.ServiceCompletionImpl.process(ServiceCompletionImpl.java:243)
>       at com.wm.app.b2b.server.invoke.ValidateProcessor.process(ValidateProcessor.java:49)
>       at com.wm.app.b2b.server.invoke.PipelineProcessor.process(PipelineProcessor.java:171)
>       at com.wm.app.b2b.server.ACLManager.process(ACLManager.java:303)
>       at com.wm.app.b2b.server.invoke.DispatchProcessor.process(DispatchProcessor.java:34)
>       at com.wm.app.b2b.server.AuditLogManager.process(AuditLogManager.java:375)
>       at com.wm.app.b2b.server.invoke.InvokeManager.invoke(InvokeManager.java:547)
>       at com.wm.app.b2b.server.invoke.InvokeManager.invoke(InvokeManager.java:386)
>       at com.wm.app.b2b.server.ServiceManager.invoke(ServiceManager.java:238)
>       at com.wm.app.b2b.server.comm.DefaultServerRequestHandler.handleMessage(DefaultServerRequestHandler.java:119)
>       at com.wm.app.b2b.server.HTTPMessageHandler.process(HTTPMessageHandler.java:164)
>       at com.wm.app.b2b.server.HTTPDispatch.handleRequest(HTTPDispatch.java:170)
>       at com.wm.app.b2b.server.Dispatch.run(Dispatch.java:362)
>       at com.wm.util.pool.PooledThread.run(PooledThread.java:127)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Someone could save me with this please? Thanks in advance!

Comment: "IllegalArgumentException: calculated end index (888984) is out of allowable range (888980..888983)" _Isn't that clear?_

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not clear to me why it is going to that index. :( I am just on index 1. Could you help me to understand this.

Comment: Could you please post the code where you try to do this? it's hard to find the bug without code!

Answer (score 0):

here is my code:

```
if(resultAssessed.equalsIgnoreCase("true")&& code.equals("-1")) {
    if(sheetName.equalsIgnoreCase("ABC")) {
        int index = my_workbook.getSheetIndex("ABC");
        if(index >=0)
            my_workbook.removeSheetAt(index);
        Sheet errorSheet= my_workbook.createSheet("ABC_Error"); 
        my_workbook.setSheetOrder("ABC_Error",index); 

        Row row = errorSheet.createRow(3);
        Cell cell = row.createCell(1);
        cell.setCellValue("Error in Data");
        errorSheet.addMergedRegion(new CellRangeAddress(3,3,1,4));
    }
}
else {
    if(sheetName.equalsIgnoreCase("ABC")){
        int index = my_workbook.getSheetIndex("ABC");
        if(index >=0)
            my_workbook.removeSheetAt(index);
```